# 14.04 what is the difference between /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.4

Tags: python3, virtualenv

In /usr/bin there is a python3 and python3.4. What is the difference?  If I am setting up virtualenv for 3.4 do I need to point it to the 3.4 file, or does the python3 act like a meta package?

Comment: Try `readlink /usr/bin/python3`.

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/bin/python`, `/usr/bin/python2`  and `/usr/bin/python3` are just symbolic links to a Python executable for convenient access to a Python 2/3 interpreter or just a python interpreter. In 14.04 they point to:

- `/usr/bin/python` → `/usr/bin/python2.7`
- `/usr/bin/python2` → `/usr/bin/python2.7`
- `/usr/bin/python3` → `/usr/bin/python3.4`

In combination with virtualenv you should use the executable directly: `/usr/bin/python2.7` or `/usr/bin/python3.4`, but the symbolic links should work as well.